# Alternate form of Kolmogorov Extension Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

(Kolmogorov extension theorem, alternate form) For each natural number ${n}$, let ${\mu_n}$ be a probability measure on ${{\bf R}^n}$ with the property that

$\displaystyle \mu_{n+1}( B \times {\bf R} ) = \mu_n(B)$

for ${n \geq 1}$ and any box ${B = [a_1,b_1] \times \dots \times [a_n,b_n]}$ in ${{\bf R}^n}$, where we identify ${{\bf R}^n \times {\bf R}}$ with ${{\bf R}^{n+1}}$ in the usual manner. Show that there exists a unique probability measure ${\mu_{\bf N}}$ on ${{\bf R}^{\bf N}}$ (with the product ${\sigma}$-algebra, or equivalently the Borel ${\sigma}$-algebra on the product topology) such that

$\displaystyle \mu_{\bf N}( \{ (\omega_i)_{i \in {\bf N}}: (\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n) \in E \} ) = \mu_n(E)$

for all ${n \geq 1}$ and Borel sets ${E \subset {\bf R}^n}$.

**Question**: For part of the proof, I want to show that $\mu_n$ obeys the compatibility condition that for any $m \leq n$, we have $\displaystyle \mu_n(\pi^{-1}_{\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m}(B)) = \mu_m(B)$ for any box $B$ in $\mathbf{R}^m$, where $\pi_{\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m}: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$ is the projection map onto the first $m$ coordinates. Is this attainable from the given?